# How to extract a portion of TM_FILENAME_BASE

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I'm trying to write a snippet to quickly/easily generate an interface for a repository. If I name the file `IFooRepository` I'd like the snippet to place the word `Foo` in a few areas.

I'm assuming this can be achieved by transforming the TM_FILENAME_BASE variable provided out of the box, but am having a hard time figuring it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.  Man I suck at regular expressions and was thinking about this all wrong

`${TM_FILENAME_BASE/I(.*)Repository/$1/}`