# Snippet to split variable TM_FILENAME_BASE in two parts for VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have a file with the name `KEY - My text with spaces.md` and what to split that filename as a Visual Studio Code (vscode) Snippet. **The Goal:** Split the file name in `KEY` and in `My text with spaces` and drop the splitter `-`.

I was able to get the last part (value) in the correct way. But I am failing with the first part (key).

Q1: How can I get the `key` part?
Q2: Is there a better way to get the `value` part?

markdown.code-snippets file

```
{
    "Add new acronym":{
        "prefix": "kw-new-acronym",
        "scope": "markdown",
        "body": [
            "key  : \"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/[^0-9^a-z]//gi}\"",
            "value: \"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/\\w* - //gi}\""
        ],
        "description": "Add new acronym"
    }
}
```

Some Links:

- [VScode Snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_snippet-syntax)
- [Stackoverflow Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459540/how-to-extract-a-portion-of-tm-filename-base)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for Q1 and Q2, it is quiet easy :-)

markdown.code-snippets file

```
{
    "Add new acronym":{
        "prefix": "kw-new-acronym",
        "scope": "markdown",
        "body": [
            "key  : \"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*) - (.*)/$1/}\"",
            "value: \"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(.*) - (.*)/$2/}\""
        ],
        "description": "Add new acronym"
    }
}
```